# php multiple selector tag issues

Tags: php, mysql

hi i have this multiple selector where i can only match one item at a time from the MySql database please help. i have use implode and explode to insert and update the string. i want to select multiple items from the list.

```
<!-- Select Multiple -->
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="skills">Skills</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<select id="skills" name="skills[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
<option value="0" 

<?php 
if(isset($skills)){
(explode(" ",$skills));
in_array('0', $skills) ? 'selected' : '';
?>>php</option>



<option value="1" <?php 
in_array('1', $skills) ? 'selected' : '';
?>>WordPress</option>


<option value="2" <?php 
in_array('2', $skills) ? 'selected' : '';
?>>HTML</option>


<option value="3" <?php 
in_array('3', $skills) ? 'selected' : '';
?>>CSS</option>


<option value="4" <?php 
in_array('4', $skills) ? 'selected' : '';
}
?>>JS</option>


</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the code, what is the problem ?

Comment: i can only select an single item i want to select multiple items

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit unclear, but you have to assign value of exploding to `$skills` again:

```
$skills = explode(" ", $skills);
```

Then to check if skill is selected do this:

```
in_array('0', $skills) ? 'selected' : '';
```

Hope it helps.

Also make sure you have `multiple` attribute set on `select` element and name has array braces `[]`:

```
<select multiple name="skills[]">
```

Comment: No problem, glad if it helped